# iOS app embedded image scroll vs follow-link nuisance

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, ios-app

SE app version 1.4.3.7 on iOS 9.2.1.

In iOS apps in general, one is accustomed to a link being followed upon pressing and then releasing the link.  Also, the standard behavior is that, if you press (the link becomes "active") and then decide you don't want to follow the link you can move your finger up or down to scroll, which cancels the follow-link behavior when you lift your finger.  In other words, a press followed by vertical motion is interpreted as a scroll, not follow-link.

The iOS Stack Exchange app has for a long time had an annoying "feature" where if you touch an image embedded in a post and your touch gets captured as a link-activation, then the scroll-to-cancel-link behavior does not work.  Putting your finger down on an image (i.e. as part of normal scrolling in the post) captures your press and will then erroneously follow the link.  Very occasionally, you can avoid following the link by quickly flicking your finger off the left or right side of the screen, but this works less than 10% of the time.

It seems you can avoid the initial capture if your finger is already moving up or down at the instant it touches the screen, but the SE app seems to be the only one that requires this level of dexterity to avoid unwanted link-following behavior.

This does not seem to happen on regular links, only embedded images.

In previous versions following the link launched the embedded browser.  In the most recent version it now launches Google Chrome and pulls up the image in a new tab, which takes longer and is much more annoying.

Basically, the distinction between normal scrolling and following a link to an embedded image does not seem to work correctly.

Comment: YES! I do this nearly every single day and it annoys me to death

Comment: @BrianNickel Any chance this can get added to the current priority list? Can you at least confirm that it is a known bug?  It really interferes with using the app on an iPad.

Comment: This will be fixed in the next release, shipping in February.

Comment: Thanks!! This will be much appreciated.